# Why am I exceeding the maximum recursion depth

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion

I am attempting to make a Countdown solver from the popular TV show which, given 6 numbers and a target number, runs through possible solutions till one is found and then returns it.
I am not looking for a super optimised version, only a simple function that would be easy to add in to a larger program (my end goal).
When I run my code, it states that the maximum recursion depth is exceeded and I am not sure why.
I would think that it should only run 5 recursive calls along with 1 or 2 functions like int() within those.
Can anybody explain why I have this error?

The function works (or is supposed to work) as follows:
The list of numbers is passed as a string and each combination of 2 numbers are combined using all the 4 possible operations (bearing in mind a + b = b + a) in a for loop. This is checked against the target.
The result replaces the two numbers in the original list to create a list with one less element. e.g.

```
["7","9","50","25","75","100"] => ["63","50","25","75","100"]
```

where 7 and 9 have been replaced by 63, (7 * 9) This is where the function calls itself with the new list. This process continues until the list only has two elements in which case the function will return "Q" if nothing has been found (causing each subsequent call to return "Q").
If ever the solution is found, the string representing the operation is returned e.g. "(7 * 9)".
Due to the recursive nature, in this example where 63 was calculated first, when "(5 + 63)" is returned, 63 should be replaced to give "(5 + (7 * 9))". This means the final method is eventually returned.

Please comment if I haven't explained it properly and I can try again.

```
import itertools as i

target=input("What is the target number? ")

def solve(l):
  global count
  if len(l) == 2:
    count+=1
    if int(l[0]) + int(l[1]) == target:
      return "("+l[0] +" + "+l[1]+")"
    count+=1
    if int(l[0]) - int(l[1]) == target:
      return "("+l[0] +" - "+l[1]+")"
    count+=1
    if int(l[0]) * int(l[1]) == target:
      return "("+l[0] +" * "+l[1]+")"
    count+=1
    if int(l[0]) / int(l[1]) == target:
      return "("+l[0] +" / "+l[1]+")"
    count+=1
    if int(l[1]) - int(l[0]) == target:
      return "("+l[0] +" - "+l[1]+")"
    count+=1
    if int(l[1]) / int(l[0]) == target:
      return "("+l[1] +" / "+l[0]+")"
    else:
      return "Q"
  else:
    ct = list(i.combinations(l, 2))
    for item in ct:
      count+=1
      resulta1=int(item[0])+int(item[1])
      if resulta1 == target:
        return "("+item[0] +" + "+item[1]+")"
      count+=1
      resulta2=int(item[0])-int(item[1])
      if resulta2 == target:
        return "("+item[0] +" - "+item[1]+")"
      count+=1
      resulta3=int(item[0])*int(item[1])
      if resulta3 == target:
        return "("+item[0] +" * "+item[1]+")"
      count+=1
      resulta4=int(item[0])/int(item[1])
      if resulta4 == target:
        return "("+item[0] +" / "+item[1]+")"
      count+=1
      resulta5=int(item[1])-int(item[0])
      if resulta5 == target:
        return "("+item[0] +" - "+item[1]+")"
      count+=1
      resulta6=int(item[1])+int(item[0])
      if resulta6 == target:
        return "("+item[1] +" / "+item[0]+")"
      intl = [el for el in l]
      intl.remove(item[0])
      intl.remove(item[1])
      newl=intl
      newl.append(str(resulta1))
      res1=solve(newl)
      if res1 != "Q":
        return res1.replace(str(resulta1),"("+item[0] +" + "+item[1]+")")
      newl=intl
      newl.append(str(resulta2))
      res2=solve(newl)
      if res2 != "Q":
        return res2.replace(str(resulta2),"("+item[0] +" - "+item[1]+")")
      newl=intl
      newl.append(str(resulta3))
      res3=solve(newl)
      if res3 != "Q":
        return res3.replace(str(resulta3),"("+item[0] +" * "+item[1]+")")
      newl=intl
      newl.append(str(resulta4))
      res4=solve(newl)
      if res4 != "Q":
        return res4.replace(str(resulta4),"("+item[0] +" / "+item[1]+")")
      newl=intl
      newl.append(str(resulta5))
      res5=solve(newl)
      if res5 != "Q":
        return res5.replace(str(resulta5),"("+item[1] +" - "+item[0]+")")
      newl=intl
      newl.append(str(resulta6))
      res6=solve(newl)
      if res6 != "Q":
        return res6.replace(str(resulta6),"("+item[1] +" / "+item[0]+")")
      else:
        return "Q"

lis=input("Enter numbers separated by commas: ").split(",")
count=0
solution = solve(lis)
print(count)
```

A note would be that I use the Online IDE Replit which may have a different maximum recursion depth.

Comment: A) `global`? Uh-oh. B) These repeated `int` conversions are serious clutter. Convert once, compare many times. These values should probably be converted before being put in the `l` argument.

Comment: The reason why I am converting to int is because I will use it as a string as well. Is there a better way to do this

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by global?, are the arguments not separate between function calls?

Comment: It's best to avoid using global variables and keep your functions more *functional*, limiting side-effects. When doing recursion this often involves passing in one additional argument, in this case like `solve(l, count)`. It's not clear why this needs to be `global` here.

Comment: `newl=intl` does not create a new list. `newl.append(str(resulta2))` will just make your list longer and longer... the cause of infinite recursion.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realise it didn't create a new list. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

A few pieces of advice:

- Don't use keyword `global`; instead, use function arguments.
- Don't use huge "forests of if" with repetitive code; instead, use a loop that iterates over the options.
- If a function deals with arithmetic, then store integers as integers in this function, not as strings that need to be repeatedly converted to integers.
- Use a separate function to deal with pretty printing your expression as a string.
- The terminal case of the recursive function in your code is `len(l) == 2`; but you probably need a terminal case for `len(l) == 1` as well! For instance if you start with a list of three elements, then your code will remove two and you'll have one left.
- Since you already use `itertools.combinations` to find all the ways to split the numbers, there is no need to check separately for `l[0]-l[1]` and `l[1]-l[0]`; just trust `combinations` to split the numbers with any possible combination on the left and on the right.

Following the logic of your code, but applying my own advice:

```py
import itertools as i

from operator import add, sub, mul

def div(a, b):
    try:
        if a % b == 0:
            return a // b
        else:
            return float('inf')
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        return float('inf')

rsub = lambda a,b: sub(b,a)
rdiv = lambda a,b: div(b,a)

op_list = (add, sub, mul, div, rsub, rdiv)

def all_splits(seq):
    "all_splits([1,2,3,4,5]) --> ((1, 2), (3, 4, 5))  ((1, 3), (2, 4, 5))  ((1, 4), (2, 3, 5))  ((1, 5), (2, 3, 4))  ((2, 3), (1, 4, 5))  ((2, 4), (1, 3, 5))  ((2, 5), (1, 3, 4))  ((3, 4), (1, 2, 5))  ((3, 5), (1, 2, 4))  ((4, 5), (1, 2, 3))"
    s = set(range(len(seq)))
    for c in i.combinations(s, 2):
        yield tuple(seq[j] for j in c), tuple(seq[j] for j in s.difference(c))

def complement_target(target, op, left):
    '''left op right == target    <--->    right == target revop left'''
    revop = {add: sub, sub: rsub, mul: div, div: rdiv, rsub: add, rdiv: mul}
    return revop[op](target, left)

def solve(target, numbers):
    if len(numbers) == 1:
        if target == numbers[0]:
            yield numbers[0]
    elif len(numbers) == 2:
        a, b = numbers
        for op in op_list:
            if target == op(a, b):
                yield (a, op, b)
    else:
        for (a,b),right_numbers in all_splits(numbers):
            for left_op in op_list:
                left_target = left_op(a,b)
                for op in op_list:
                    right_target = complement_target(target, op, left_target)
                    if op(left_target, right_target) == target: # (x / y) * y ?=? x
                        for right_expr in solve(right_target, right_numbers):
                            yield ((a, left_op, b), op, right_expr)

def stringify(expr):
    opnames = {add:'{a} + {b}',sub:'{a} - {b}',mul:'{a} * {b}',div:'{a} / {b}',rsub:'{b} - {a}',rdiv:'{b} / {a}'}
    if isinstance(expr, int):
        return str(expr)
    elif len(expr) == 3:
        left_expr, op, right_expr = expr
        a=stringify(left_expr)
        b=stringify(right_expr)
        return ''.join(('(', opnames[op].format(a=a,b=b), ')'))
    else:
        raise ValueError(expr)

def main():
    for target,numbers in ((10,(1,2,3,4)), (9,(1,2,3,4,27))):
        for expr in solve(target, numbers):
            print(target, ' == ', stringify(expr))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

```
10  ==  ((1 + 2) + (3 + 4))
10  ==  ((3 * 4) - (1 * 2))
10  ==  ((3 * 4) - (2 / 1))
...
10  ==  ((3 + 4) + (1 + 2))
10  ==  ((3 * 4) - (1 * 2))
10  ==  ((3 * 4) - (2 / 1))
9  ==  ((1 + 2) + ((27 - 3) / 4))
9  ==  ((1 + 2) - ((3 - 27) / 4))
9  ==  (((4 - 3) * 27) / (1 + 2))
...
9  ==  ((27 / 3) / ((4 - 1) - 2))
9  ==  ((27 / 3) / ((4 - 2) - 1))
9  ==  ((27 / 3) / ((4 / 2) - 1))
```

Comment: Wow, thank you very much for your help. I think I understand all of what you've said, you've been very helpful